# Trigonometric indentity proof

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, angle

How to prove the following identity?

$$\frac{\mathrm{sin}(2a)-\mathrm{sin}(2b)}{\mathrm{sin}(2a)+\mathrm{sin}(2b)}=\frac{\mathrm{tan}(a-b)}{\mathrm{tan}(a+b)}$$

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You are more likely to get help here if you show some effort.

Comment: How about $\tan (a-b) = \frac {\sin (a-b)}{\cos (a-b)} = \frac {\sin a\cos b - \cos a\sin b}{\cos a\cos b + \sin a\sin b}$  Then do the similar for $\tan (a+b)$  Then simplify.

Comment: Just express everything in terms of $t_1 = \tan a$ and $t_2 = \tan b$,
$${\rm LHS} 
= \frac{\frac{2t_1}{1+t_1^2} - \frac{2t_2}{1+t_2^2}}{
\frac{2t_1}{1+t_1^2} + \frac{2t_2}{1+t_2^2}}
=
\frac{t_1(1+t_2^2)-t_2(1+t_1^2)}{t_1(1+t_2^2)+t_2(1+t_1^2)}
=\frac{(t_1-t_2)(1-t_1t_2)}{(t_1+t_2)(1+t_1t_2)}
= \frac{\frac{t_1-t_2}{1+t_1t_2}}{\frac{t_1+t_2}{1-t_1t_2}} = {\rm RHS}
$$

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
   \dfrac{\tan(a-b)}{\tan(a+b)}
   &= \dfrac{\sin(a-b) \cos(a+b)}{\cos(a-b) \sin(a+b)} \\
   &= \dfrac{2 \sin(a-b) \cos(a+b)}{2 \sin(a+b) \cos(a-b)} \\
   &= \dfrac{\sin((a-b)+(a+b)) + \sin((a-b)-(a+b))}
            {\sin((a+b)+(a-b)) + \sin((a+b)-(a-b))} \\
   &= \dfrac{\sin(2a) - \sin(2b)}
            {\sin(2a) + \sin(2b)} \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Use the following substitution $$\pmatrix{a & b} = \pmatrix{ \frac{c+d}{2} & \frac{c-d}{2} } $$

So now we have:

$$ \begin{align} 
  \sin(2 a) & = \cos(c) \sin(d) + \sin(c) \cos(d) \\
  \sin(2 b) & = \sin(c) \cos(d) - \cos(c) \sin(d)
\end{align} $$

and

$$ \begin{align} 
  \sin(2 a) - \sin(2 b) & = 2 \cos(c) \sin(d) = 2 \cos(a+b) \sin(a-b)  \\
  \sin(2 a) + \sin(2 b) & = 2 \sin(c) \cos(d) = 2 \sin(a+b) \cos(a-b)
\end{align} $$

Now divide the above to get your identity.